# Why does std::reference_wrapper explicitly define a copy assignment operator?

Tags: c++

A std::reference_wrapper explicitly declares the copy assignment operator. Why? This should prevent move construction/assignment from being implicitly defined so my assumption is that they do not want you to move a std::reference_wrapper, but I am not sure why that would matter.

If you look at the "possible implementation", they just default the operator:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/operator%3D

Just looking for some history on why the committee felt the need for this.

Comment: There is no "possible implementation" on this page. Is it the right page?

Comment: "possible implementation" is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They declare it because it has work to do.

Yes, this inhibits an automatically-generated move constructor. No, that doesn't matter. The authors would have had to define their own anyway (for the same reason they need to create a copy constructor), except that there is no use in "moving" something that doesn't own a resource. It would be the same as a copy.

That doesn't mean that a `std::reference_wrapper` isn't movable, it just means that "moving" one is the same as copying it. And there's no point in implementing that twice!

Comment: Honestly I think this is best explanation I can come up with as well. In the end, the move would be the same as a copy, so there is not need to add it.

Answer (score 6):

> This should prevent move construction/assignment from being implicitly defined

`std::reference_wrapper` is a non-owning reference (a pointer, really), move operation is no different from copy. Don't confuse it with `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I'm not, really looking more for why move would not have been added. My guess is it is because the reference_wrapper is just a pointer, so a move would be the same as a copy.

Answer (score 3):

`std::reference_wrapper` is an object with reference-like semantics. But unlike built in references, a `reference_wrapper` can be re-bound, copied and moved. This allows it it to be used in standard containers. So I do not understand your confusion, by its design a `reference_wrapper` is supposed to be copyable and movable.

Comment: The question is why it is not movable.

Comment: Although you can use a move, it is not actually moved since the implicit move is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what state you would expect the moved-from `std::reference_wrapper` to be in.  You don't want to have a reference wrapper referring to something that doesn't exist if you can help it